# Android add border to button

Tags: android, button, onclick, border

I need to add a border to my button when it's clicked, and i need the background from the button (which i get remotely, so i cant use `R.drawable.picture` etc) to remain the way it is.

In short, when clicked, i want to add a border to my (custom backgrounded) button.

How do i do this? I've read many many pages and questions on borders, buttons, shapes, selectors, etc, but the majority of them involve xml, but because i don't have the background from the buttons before starting the applications, I think i'm bound to programmatically adding and removing the border. Again, i need to retain the custom button background, but add a small onclick border.

NOTE: I use this on all buttons, with different sizes. So applying a drawable is not a real option. I think i'm bound to some sort of drawing a rectangle around the clicked button.

NOTE2: again, I have a background which must be applied. the border is merely a small indicator for onclick events. So i cant put in the XML that the background is some sort of selector

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444194/android-programatically-create-button-border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define layer_list in xml with 2 layers: one for your image, the other one for your border and use this layer list as a drawable for your button's pressed state

Comment: all the buttons are differently sized. Is that is a problem?

Answer (score 5):

**Btn.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#343434" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#171717" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="5dp"
            android:top="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:bottom="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#343434"
            android:endColor="#275296"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="0dp"
            android:color="#171717" />
        <corners
            android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="5dp"
            android:top="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:bottom="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Here stroke attribute will appear as border to the button when clicked.

save this in drawable folder. and use as like below

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="Button"/>
```

Comment: This works on a button without a background. However, buttons with already a background applied don't show any borders on click.

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong did you achieve this? I mean to set a border with background?

Comment: @System.exit Yes, but not through the XML files, as the resources I received where from an external source. Long while ago, but I think I took the Image, made it a layer on a LayerDrawable, and made the border a 9patch drawable, and put that in the LayerDrawable as well. Although it worked, it didn't look all that nicely, so I'd suggest reading some other posts and make a custom button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try having a `9.png` with just a black border around a transparent area. This you could apply in the "pressed" state of the button, using a selector.